# F# Class with Generics : 'constructor deprecated' error

Tags: class, f#, generics

I am trying to create a a class that will store a time series of data - organized by groups, but I had some compile errors so I stripped down to the basics (just a simple instantiation) and still can't overcome the compile error.  I was hoping some one may have seen this issue before. Clas is defined as:

```
type TimeSeriesQueue<'V, 'K when 'K: comparison> = class
        val private m_daysInCache: int  
        val private m_cache: Map<'K, 'V list ref > ref;
        val private m_getKey: ('V -> 'K) ;

        private new(getKey)  = {
            m_cache = ref Map.empty
            m_daysInCache  = 7 ;
            m_getKey = getKey ;
        }

end
```

So that looks OK to me (it may not be, but doesnt have any errors or warnings) - the instantiation gets the error:

```
type tempRec = {
    someKey: string ;
    someVal1: int ;
    someVal2: int ;
}

let keyFunc r:tempRec = r.someKey
// error occurs on the following line
let q = new TimeSeriesQueue<tempRec, string> keyFunc
```

> This construct is deprecated: The use
>   of the type syntax 'int C' and 'C 
>   ' is not permitted here. Consider
>   adjusting this type to be written in
>   the form 'C'

*NOTE* This may be simple stupidity - I am just getting back from holiday and my brain is still on time zone lag...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The compiler is just saying that you need to enclose parameters of the constructor in parentheses:

```
// the following should work fine
let q = new TimeSeriesQueue<tempRec, string>(keyFunc)
```

There are some other issues though - the constructor needs to be public (otherwise you cannot call it) and the parameter of `keyFunc` should be also in parentheses (otherwise, the compiler will think that the type annotation is for the result of the function):

```
let keyFunc (r:tempRec) = r.someKey
```

You may also consider using implicit constructor syntax which makes class declarations a lot simpler in F#. Parameters of the constructor automatically become available in the body of the class and you can declare (private) fields simply using `let`:

```
type TimeSeriesQueue<'V, 'K when 'K: comparison>(getKey : 'V -> 'K) =
  let daysInCache = 7  
  let cache = ref Map.empty

  member x.Foo() = ()
```

Comment: I did notice the typo with the keyFunc - must have occured as I was simplifying my code to post.  I did add parens around the instantiation and it just generated a second compilation error:

"Method or object constructor 'TimeSeriesQueue`2' not found"

I am not opposed to changing class syntax to implicit - but i should be able to solve it explicitly as well...